# Unresolved external symbols using Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Community and Allegro5 Nuget packages

Tags: c++, visual-studio, allegro5, linker-warning

I understand how linker errors work/form in a program, but can't figure out how the library I'm using is not linked correctly to my code. I installed using NuGet, so it installed and setup automatically, I included what I needed to, as shown below, and still it doesn't link.

For more context, I am working on making a game with Allegro 5 and MSVS 2015 Community edition, and in the project I currently have Main.cpp, GameManager.h and .cpp, and PhysicsObject.h and .cpp files, what's in them isn't really important for this linking issue, aside from the order in which certain things are added (such as the #include placement), but this issue is persistent in even the basic tutorial program as shown on the allegro wiki site below (I have the same configuration in my game as that program, and both get the same linking error pertaining to Allegro functions).

Tutorial Link: https://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Windows,_Visual_Studio_2015_and_Nuget_Allegro_5

I have setup a basic program using the exact example given on the tutorial posted above, and still get unresolved external symbols (relating to the Allegro functions in it). I don't know if somehow old installs of Allegro or Visual Studio could cause this error (because I have had previous installs of both, but tried to get rid of all the files pertaining to them), but I will link screenshots of what I've done and what I am getting from output to make this more clear. (I don't have 10 reputation to post images properly, since this is my first post, but I do have lightshot screenshots)

Output Window: http://prntscr.com/kpvhjn
 Add-ons Active: http://prntscr.com/kpvi83

I also have this at the top of the header file known as GameManager.h (the file the linker isn't able to resolve functions for).

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <allegro5/allegro.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro_image.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro_audio.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro_primitives.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro_font.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro_ttf.h>
#include "PhysicsObject.h"
```

I just can't figure out why this isn't linking correctly,any insight or help would be appreciated. If you need any other information to figure this out, I'd be glad to post it.

Comment: What library type did you link to with Nuget? It looks like a matter of mixing up import and export libraries.